# c# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to select multiple column in DB and store in array but keep getting this error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

it should return me something like "FunctionCode-ActivityCode"

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    DEV_Context OE = new DEV_Context();
    string role = OE.UserRefs.Where(x => x.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault().RoleName;

    string[] result = OE.RolePermissionRefs
        .Where(x => x.RoleName == role && x.StatusCode == "A")
        .Select(x => new { FunctionCode = x.FunctionCode, ActivityCode = x.ActivityCode }.ToString())
        .ToArray();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if it would work, it wouldn't give you the expected result.You are calling `ToString` on an anonymous object. If you just want to concatenate values you can try:

```
string[] result = OE.RolePermissionRefs
        .Where(x => x.RoleName == role && x.StatusCode == "A")
        .Select(x => new { x.FunctionCode, x.ActivityCode })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => string.Join("-", x.FunctionCode, x.ActivityCode))
        .ToArray();
```

The reason why `ToString` doesn't work is already explained in the error message.It can't be translated to SQL.So you need to load result into memory (e.g using `AsEnumerable` in the above code) and then project them.

Comment: Can also use `x => string.Format("{{ FunctionCode = {0}, ActivityCode = {1} }}", x.FunctionCode, x.ActivityCode)` instead of the `Join`. This should look like the `ToString` implementation on anonymous types without actually creating an instance of one.

Answer (score 0):

ToString() is available only in EF 6.0 and higher. In your case you could just call ToArray() before Select and do something like Selman suggested.